# Is it possible to create 8-players game in Worms Battlegrounds on PS4?

Tags: worms-battlegrounds

Is it possible to create 8-players local game in Worms Battlegrounds on PS4?

Comment: The PS4 tag is not appropriate here. That tag is used when the question is specific to a feature of the PS4 console itself, not because the game is on PS4. Other users will know you are on PS4 anyway since you specify it in the title. You can read the tag usage [here.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/ps4/info)